# For what value of $x$ is the following number a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, integers, square-numbers

I've the following number:

$$1+12x^2(1+x)$$

For what value of $x\ge2$ and $x\in\mathbb{N}$ is the number $1+12x^2(1+x)$ a perfect square?

Comment: Are you trying to generalize from a given $n$?

Comment: If you want $x$ to be integer, then it's a family of elliptic curves, and you are asking what are the integral points on every single curve. There is no simple answer to the question.

Comment: Echoing Whatsup, each value of $n$ can lead to different casework. If you have a particular value of $n$, please state it.

Comment: If $n=1$ then $x$ is given by a cubic equation whose $3$ roots are indexed by an integer, $m$. [(Link)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+12x%5E3%2B12x%5E2%2B1-m%5E2). The solution is not particularly neat. For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $m>1$, there is only one real root.

Comment: @Jam I'm looking for perfect squares in the range of $x\ge2$

Comment: @gyiupol Then the solution I linked will still work but you will require $m>\sqrt{145}=12.04$.

Comment: @Jam I do not see why solving a third-degree polynomial solve the problem? I'm sorry.

Comment: Because you gave us one. If $1+12x^2(1+x)=m^2$ for some integer $m$, then $x$ is a [root](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialRoots.html) of the cubic equation $12x^3+12x^2+1-m^2$.

Comment: @Jam Yes true, but $x\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Please put all the information into the question when you pose it. You've changed it $3$ times now.

Comment: @Jam I'm sorry I will remember it for next time.

Comment: So you have $$1+3\cdot(2x)^2\cdot(1+x)=n^2\iff 3\cdot(2x)^2\cdot(1+x)=(n+1)(n-1)$$ Observe that $4\mid (n+1)(n-1)\implies n$ is odd and can therefore be written as $2k+1, $ $k\in\mathbb Z$. Hence $$1+3\cdot(2x)^2\cdot(1+x)=(2k+1)^2\iff 3x^2\cdot(1+x)=k^2+k=k\cdot(k+1)$$

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Yes so what can we conclude from that?

Comment: There's actually *almost* nothing to conclude, but I thought that it might be simpler to look for integer solutions of the equation $$3x^2\cdot(x+1)=k\cdot(k+1)$$ rather than of your equation...

Comment: Let the natural number be $y$. Then $y^2 = 1 + 12x^2(1+x) = 12x^3 + 12x^2 + 1$. Let $y = \frac{w}{12}$ and $x = \frac{z}{12} - \frac{1}{3}$. When substituted into the original equation, you get the elliptic curve $w^2 = z^3 - 48z + 272$, with $w = 12y$ and $z = 12x + 4$.

Comment: Solve for the integral points of $w^2 = z^3 - 48z + 272$ and only take the solutions $(z, w)$ if $w \equiv 0 \bmod 12$ and $z \equiv 4 \bmod 12$.

Answer (score 1):

$y^2=12x^2(1+x)+1\tag{1}$
Multiplying $12$ on both sides and let $X=12x, Y=12y$ then we get

$Y^2 = X^3+12X^2+144\tag{2}$

Using online Magma calculator as follows.

$E$:=EllipticCurve($[0, 12, 0, 0, 144]$);
IntegralPoints($E$);

It says that all integral points are $ [ (-12 : 12 : 1), (-8 : -20 : 1), (-3 : 15 : 1), (0 : -12 : 1), (4 : 20 : 1),
 (12 : -60 : 1), (48 : -372 : 1), (72 : 660 : 1), (1717 : -71395 : 1) ]$.

Hence all positive integral points are $(x,y)=(4,31),(6,55)$ with $x\geqq2.$