# When is the number $81 + 60 x (1 + x) (-2 + 5 x)$ a perfect square for $x\ge2$ and $x\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, integers, square-numbers

I've the following number:

$$81 + 60 x (1 + x) (-2 + 5 x)$$

For what value of $x\ge2$ and $x\in\mathbb{N}$ is the number $81 + 60 x (1 + x) (-2 + 5 x)$ a perfect square?

Comment: Your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458677/242) is similar. What is their relationship, e.g. why are you interested in the square values of these particular polynomials?

Comment: This is better than your previous question, although the `real-analysis` tag is irrelevant. It can be easily solved with a computer algebra system, though.

Answer (score 3):

We have the equation $y^2 = 300 x^3 + 180 x^2 - 120 x + 81$.

We re-write it as $(300y)^2 = (300x)^3 + 180(300x)^2 - 36000(300x) + 7290000$.

Now paste the follow codes

```
E = EllipticCurve([0, 180, 0, -36000, 7290000])
P = E.integral_points()
for p in P:
    if p[0] % 300 == 0:
        print(p[0] // 300, p[1] // 300)
```

in [this page](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and press "Evaluate", and we get all integral solutions: $(x, y) = (-1, 9), (0, 9), (1, 21)$.

Comment: so no solutions for $x\ge 2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That's right.

Comment: @WhatsUp So there are no more solutions? Can that be proven?

Comment: The result is proven, assuming that the software doesn't have a bug. However understanding how the algorithm works might require much knowledge about elliptic curves.

Comment: @WhatsUp Can this algorithm also be used to tackle the previous problem?

Comment: This algorithm can be used on the previous problem for every given $n$, but it should be mentioned that the algorithm doesn't guarantee to work in all cases. In that sense, it is not an "algorithm". Try it with the curve $y^2 = x^3 + 123$ and you'll get the message: "Unable to compute Mordell-Weil basis of Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 123 over Rational Field, hence unable to compute integral points."

Comment: @WhatsUp So, using this code: E = EllipticCurve([0, 12, 0, 0, 144])
P = E.integral_points()
for p in P:
    if p[0] % 12 == 0:
        print(p[0] // 12, p[1] // 12) I can find all the solutions to my previous question?

Comment: Yes, try it yourself! I get $(-1, 1)
(0, 1)
(1, 5)
(4, 31)
(6, 55)$. P.S. I didn't see that you modified the previous question to a special $n$. I should have answered there...

Comment: @WhatsUp What is the general way of putting in the coefficients into the EllipticCurve formula into the code?

Comment: See the beginning of the documentation here: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/constructor.html These are coefficients of a *Weierstrass equation*.