# Finding perfect squares in a quadratic equation

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, elliptic-curves, square-numbers

Well, I have a number $\text{p}$ that is given by:

$$\text{p}=9+108x^2(1+x)\tag1$$

I want to find $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\text{p}$ is a perfect square.

> I found no solutions. Is there a way to prove that there aren't any solutions? Except for the obvious ones: $x=0$ and $x=\pm1$.

---

**My work**

Since $\text{p}$ must be a perfect square we can write:

$$\text{p}^2=9+108x^2(1+x)\tag2$$

Now, because $\text{p}^2\ge0$ we need:

$$9+108x^2(1+x)\ge0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x\ge-\frac{1}{3}\left(1+2^\frac{2}{3}+2^{-\frac{2}{3}}\right)\approx-1.07245\tag3$$

Comment: For $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, another solution is $x = -1$. Do you want to exclude that one as well?

Comment: @Jan Have you forgotten that you asked essentially the same question a few weeks ago ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463339/proving-that-a-list-of-perfect-square-numbers-is-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $9$, you want to find $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $12x^3 +12x^2 +1$ is a square number.

$x=0$ is one obvious solution. Even if you restrict $x$ to strictly positive integers there is another obvious solution.

(Note that this was posted before Jan added “Except for $x=0$ and $x=1$” to his question)

Comment: But this does not prove that there aren't any more solutions?

Comment: I assume you're referring to $x = 1$ giving $25$?

Comment: @Jan Your question was “Is there a way to prove that there aren’t any solutions ?”. The answer is no, because there are at least two solutions. Now you are asking a different question.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by $9$, you'll get something similar to $$p^2 - 1=12 x^2(1+x)$$

First, let's ssume $x$ is odd.  Then either $x^2\mid p-1$ or $x^2\mid p+1$. Suppose $x^2\mid p-1$, so that $p=1+kx^2$, then $ k^2x^4+2kx^2=12 x^2(1+x)\Rightarrow k^2x^2-12x-12+2k=0\Rightarrow k\in \{\pm 1, \pm 2\}.$ You should get something similar for the other case.

Now suppose $x$ is even, say $x=2^qy$ with $y$ odd. Then the equation becomes $$p^2 - 1=3\times 4^{q+1} y^2(1+2^qy).$$
Then as before $y^2 \mid p\pm 1$, so that $p=\pm 1+ky^2$. This time, after simplification, we get $$k^2y^2 \pm 2k = 3\times 4^{q+1} (1+2^qy)\Rightarrow k^2y^2  - 3\times 2^{3q+2} y\pm 2k-3\times 4^{q+1}=0.$$
It follows $k^2 \mid  3\times 2^{3q+2} y \Rightarrow k=\pm 2^t,\, $ for some $t=0,1,\ldots, \left[\frac{3q+2}{2}\right].$ But you can easily see that $t\leq 1$.

Comment: This proves that there are no more solutions?

Comment: can you tell me of this proves that there are no more solutions?